# Why does partition method of quick sort not guarantee partition when low equals high

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion, quicksort

When low equals high in the below snippet, why does the below partition method of quick sort not guarantee that elements on the left side of low/high are less than the pivot and those on the right side of low/high are greater than pivot.

```
    int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
    int pivot = a[middle];

    while (low < high) 
    {
        while (a[low] < pivot) 
        {
                low++;
        }

        while (a[high] > pivot) 
        {
                high--;
        }

        if (low <= high) 
        {
                swap( a, low, high );
                low++;
                high--;
        }
    }
```

Isn't that what the definition of 'low' and 'high' are? To signify elements on the left of pivot and right of pivot once we've reached the ending condition?

Consider the below array

```
int[] a = {37, 89, 17, 51, 53, 75};
```

Here low equals high at index 1, which has the element 89. However, it's not true that index 1 is the correct position of element 89/elements on the left of index 1 are all less than 89, and elements on the right of 89 are all greater than 89.

Why is this algorithm going wrong? I was hoping that once, low equals high, we have found the correct position for that pivot, and can proceed to leave out that element, and recursively repeat the algorithm for elements on the left, and right resp.

Comment: when outermost while loop is over, you need to swap the element at high index with element at pivot(which is middle in your case) index.

Comment: This algorithm is similar to [Hoare partition scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme). The pivot value will end up in either the left or the right partition after the partitioning is done. In this case, the pivot value 17, ends up at index 0. After the loop, high == 0. The 2 recursive calls at this level will be quicksort(array, 0, 0), which does nothing, and quicksort(array, 1, 5).

Comment: @rcgldr, as you say, after the loop, high==0, only if, the outer while loop looks like: while (low <= high). My question is, why should the outer while loop run, when low==high. Why can't low==high be a stopping condition, such that elements on the left and right side of low/high are less than and greater than a[low/high] resp? In other words, why doesn't the outer loop : while (low < high) work?

Comment: @saltmangotree - With this method of partitioning, elements on the left are <= pivot, elements on the right are >= pivot. The strange combination of while(low < high) and if(low <= high) are due to the post decrements and post increments. The code could be changed to the [Hoare partition scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme), but choosing middle element as the pivot, or use median of three, which sorts array[low], array[middle], array[high], and uses array[middle] as pivot.

Comment: @avinesh Consider the input array to be int[] a = {100, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}; Are you talking about the condition while(low<high) or while(low<=high). Either way, at the end of the while loop, it would look as {10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 100, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}; and high is at index 5, which is not the correct position of element 10.

Comment: @saltmangotree ignore my previous comment,it doesn't apply to this implementation. But i think there is no need of this tedious implementation. what you can do:- find the mid element, swap with last element and then perform standard partition procedure with last element as pivot. This will be easy to understand and achieve same what user is trying to do.